# Flask - Validate several forms on Ajax request

Tags: ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to validate four forms from an Ajax request. My problem is that only one form is validated (geometry_building_form). The others do not contain errors, only an empty dictionary.

Another problem I have is that the `validate_on_submit` method does not work, I have to use the `validate` method.

This is the Flask view.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def building():
    building_parameters_form = BuildingParametersForm()
    building_geometry_form = BuildingGeometryForm()
    wind_form = WindForm()
    topography_form = TopographyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if building_geometry_form.validate() and building_parameters_form.validate() and wind_form.validate() and topography_form.validate():
            return redirect('/index')
        else:
            return jsonify(data=wind_form.errors) #Testing the wind form
    return render_template('wind/building.html', bp_form=building_parameters_form,
                            bg_form=building_geometry_form, w_form=wind_form, t_form=topography_form)
```

This is the Ajax code.

```
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#button").click(function(event) {
            var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
            var url = "{{ url_for('building') }}";
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $('#geometry-form, #parameters-form, #wind-form, #topography-form').serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
        });
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrf_token)
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormFields` are useful for editing child objects or enclosing multiple related forms on a page which are submitted and validated together. While subclassing forms captures most desired behaviours, sometimes for reusability or purpose of combining with `FieldList`, `FormField` makes sense. ([Taken from Documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#field-enclosures))

With that in mind-- you may want to create a wrapping form that encloses your sub-forms:

```
from wtforms import FormField

class BuildingForm(Form):
    building = FormField(BuildingGeometryForm)
    wind = FormField(WindForm)
    topography = FormField(TopographyForm)
```

The later when you're processing the request, `form = BuildingForm()` will allow you to do `form.validate_on_sumbit()` and it will validate and enclose the various subforms as expected.

Comment: That sounds promising. To render in Jinja is the same process?

Comment: Pretty much-- but because they're sub-forms (lets pretend there's a `description` on the `WindForm`) you would get to that form-element by doing `{{ form.wind.description }}`, so they really are nested, rather then just combined.

Comment: I'll try it. If it works, I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works great. I can even access all the errors together or filter them by field (form).